# Visual Studio debug not working on typescript (angular) - Visual Studio 2017 keeps skipping breakpoints

Tags: angular, typescript, debugging, webpack, visual-studio-2017

```
// ============================== see updates below ============================== //
```

I was trying to debug a typescript application on Visual Studio 2017 (**NOT Visual Studio Code**), but when i insert a breakpoint on a .ts file, visual studio tells me that:
*"**the breakpoint will not currently be hit no executable code is associated with this line**"*

I think I've tried all of the internet suggested solutions but nothing helped me to solve that and nothing seems to work.

Actually, this problem persists just with a single project.

I mean, i've got an other project where i can debug typescript on visual studio 2017 with breakpoints and i'm able to use them on ts files, so **i don't think it's a settings problem**.

Now, my typescript **debug settings are managed by tsconfig.json** and i think this issue may be somehow caused by something wrong in it, or maybe in my webpack.config.js file. However, that's just a hypothesis.
However:
tsconfig.json content is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "types": [ "node", "jasmine", "core-js" ],
    "noEmitOnError": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot/lib",
    "bin",
    "obj"
  ]
}
```

Webpack config file content is as follows:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    resolve: { extensions: ['.ts', '.js'] }, // .ts is first so that .ts files are prefered over js file, this ensures
    // that angular 2 components are passed through the angular2-template-loader and have their templates and styles inlined
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './App/polyfills.ts',
        'main': './App/main.ts'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './wwwroot/dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/dist/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [

            { test: /\.ts$/, include: /App/, use: ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] },
            { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'] }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]
};
```

And, as a last note, i'm using **Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack;** to enable webpack hot module replacement, with this on my startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            // HMR //
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
                {
                    HotModuleReplacement = true
                });
            }
            // HMR //

//(...) do more stuff under here
```

Have you got any solution or troubleshooting for this?

[Let me know if you need more informations]

```
// =============================================================================== //
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

Looks like that the angular project integrated in microsoft's asp net core web application project in visual studio 2017 and dot net v.2+ is born with working breakpoints and debug option.

Unfortunately, there's just an other problem with that. It's NOT an angular 5 native app, it's an angular 4 app! Moreover, any package is up-to-date. Got to update each one manually.

Once I've updated them, it seems to work. In that app, breakpoints works!

 But I can't find out why...

Comment: You can't put a breakpoint on the Typescript because the resulting javsacript is executed on the browser, not in your VS code instance.  You have to set the breakpoint in your sourcemaps in the browser.

Comment: @chrispy Thank you...but, in an other angular app on visual studio 2017 i can put breakpoints on .ts files and they works fine. How can this thing be possible? I mean, why i can put breakpoints on typescript files of that application but not in this other?
I mean, there must be a way to make them works, I think

Comment: @chrispy I'm starting to think (but it's just a hypothesis) that breakpoints works on the other project thanks to the **AngularCompilerPlugin** plugin for Webpack ( from `('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin` ).
In your opinion, does this hypothesis  make any sense?
PS: I'm using Visual Studio 2017, not visual studio code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem but yes, as you said in Update #1, the new Visual Studio proper Angular project is provided with working debug.

 In my app I found easier updating the packages to latest versions and copying my old project in the new one with working breakpoints.

But..if you read with attenction the webpack.config.js file in the new VS integrated angular app, you will certainly notice the following string:

```
        new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
            filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
            moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
        })
```

Actually, **SourceMapDevToolPlugin** provides - if configurated correctly - a real time mapping, which makes possible using breakpoints.

 Your choice if using in line source maps or not.

You should also set the property: `devtool: 'inline-source-map'`

 And enable UglifyPlugin's sourcemaps.

The only cons that I found out are:

- breakpoints are not available since the first moment that the app starts, you have to wait a few seconds
- using breakpoints is a bit slow
- using chrome console disable breakpoints

Comment: I use Angular 5, there is no `webpack.config.js` file in the project.

Comment: @Bigeyes my answer is outdated (and the question seems to be outdated too, the OP also has closed his/her account, so...), since from Angular 4 (if I remember correctly), webpack.config is hidden. You can eject it with `ng eject` command but trust me, editing webpack.js is a minefield, personally I'd rather not touch it at all. By the way, if you're looking for a way to debug an angular app, I'd suggest you to use chrome's devtools

Comment: @Bigeyes in brief, to debug with Chrome devtrools, just open Chrome's console and go to "Sources" tab. Then, in the left treeview look for "webpack" element and expand it. Then expand the dot folder (".") and from there you can debug the whole app or at least the modules that has been loaded (if you're using lazy loading). [You can also debug with VS Code](https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-angular-cli-applications-in-visual-studio-code) but in the end it relies on Chrome Devtools so using Chrome Devtools seems to be the best choice in my opinion

Comment: Thanks for the kindle reply. Actually I have two questions for Visual Studio Code debug. 1) Our company use IE/Edge as the default browser, we have to copy to url to chrome then run it. If we use chrome extension for Visual Studio Code but we run it in IE, it is still okay? 2) In .net core, we set the port in a configuration (launchsetting.json). Does the port number in chrome extension setting have to be same as the one in launchsetting.json?

Comment: @Bigeyes uhm... you catch me unprepared, man. Honestly, I've never used IE/Edge as browser due to its lack of development features and its tons of incompatibilities. I've heard that now Edge implements webkits and it's now chrome-based on certain features but I never investigated... Doing a quick research, I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50013884/9653205) but it's still unanswered and I just found answers about chrome debug so I don't think that using Edge could be the best idea... Is it really impossible to you to use Chrome instead?

Comment: @Bigeyes for your question #2, actually the port refers to Angular's Local server one. I don't see a launchsettings configuration from a while, but as I can remember, the one you write in launchsettings is just a redirect to port 4200. So go with default 4200 :)

Comment: Actually I tried port 4200, it is not working. Nut it works for the port in `launchsetting.json`

Comment: @Bigeyes Good to know, as I said, it's been a while since I last had to deal with a lanchsettings.json file so my memory is not reliable at all for that! Can I ask you how did you solved the IE/Edge debug issue? Are you using chrome now or have you found another way?

Comment: IR/Edge is still not working. I downloaded chrome debugger(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome) for Visual Studio Code. Then I debug in Visual Studio(Not Visual Studio Code) using chrome debugger. It is very interesting, if I don't have chrome debugger for Visual Studio Code, then using chrome debugger in Visual Studio(Not Visual Studio Code) failed.

Answer (score 0):

Setting webpack context to ClientApp dir (or App in TS' example) did the job for me:

```
  context: path.join(__dirname, "ClientApp"),
  entry: {
    //'main': './ClientApp/main.ts'
    'main': './main.ts'
  }
```